# Internal Server Error in IIS7.5 but not in Visual studio

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have  Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Service Pack 1  and IIS7.5 Configured in My System i am working on MVC application for Digital content Management, My application works well in Visual studio but Gives Internal Server Error when i try to open empty Folder , i have given all Rights to Application for same folder, there is no any problem for those Folders which contain files or sub folders , please suggest me on this.

Comment: Internal Server Error when i try to open empty Folder ??

Comment: What kind of Internal Server Error? The error page itself says a lot.